# What's the name of a side contents that changes heading as you scroll down the page?

Tags: navigation, menu

I want to learn more about contents menus like the one on the right of the apple developer guidance that moves as you scroll down, but I can't find the right terms to search for: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/accessibility

[image: gif of scrolling menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sidebar TOC

All the elements placed in a box on one side of the screen are called sidebars, among which are the *sidebar social links*, *sidebar menu*, *sidebar navigation* and the *sidebar TOC* which is a navigable table of contents within each page.

You will find a better example on [this page](https://kulzer.fr/fr/fr/produits/cara-print-4-0-pro.html#specifications) with dot navigation plus an expanding index menu.

[image]